# Stackoverflow error spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have this simple get request to get information based on `topicId` that is stored in db as `1486485753923`

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/get_topic_details", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity get_topic_details(@RequestParam(value="topicId") long topicId) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Topic id is " + topicId);
    TopicBean topicBean = topicService.findByTopicId(topicId);
    return new ResponseEntity(topicBean, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface TopicRepository extends JpaRepository<TopicBean, Long>{

    List<TopicBean> findTop10ByUsername(String username);

    Page<TopicBean> findAllByPage(Pageable pageable);

//    @Query("SELECT t FROM TopicBean t WHERE (t.topicId) = (:topicId)")
    TopicBean findByTopicId(long topicId);

    @Transactional
    Long deleteByTopicId(String topicId);

    List<TopicBean> findByUsername(String username);
}
```

And I get this error:

```
2017-02-17 13:44:50.542 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity seconds47.restAPI.TopicsRest.get_topic_details(long) throws java.lang.Exception]: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:978) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_102]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_102]
```

Printing Debug info:

```
2017-02-17 13:44:51.132 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error]
2017-02-17 13:44:51.132 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /error
2017-02-17 13:44:51.134 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
2017-02-17 13:44:51.134 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                : Last-Modified value for [/error] is: -1
2017-02-17 13:44:51.270 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Written [{timestamp=Fri Feb 17 13:44:51 IST 2017, status=500, error=Internal Server Error, exception=java.lang.StackOverflowError, message=No message available, path=/get_topic_details}] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@2e3900dc]
2017-02-17 13:44:51.272 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2017-02-17 13:44:51.272 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                : Successfully completed request
2017-02-17 13:44:51.306 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/get_comments_by_topicId]
2017-02-17 13:44:51.307 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /get_comments_by_topicId
2017-02-17 13:44:51.308 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public java.util.List<seconds47.beans.CommentBean> seconds47.restAPI.CommentRest.getCommentsByTopicId(java.lang.String)]
2017-02-17 13:44:51.308 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                : Last-Modified value for [/get_comments_by_topicId] is: -1
2017-02-17 13:44:51.325 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.j.c.CriteriaQueryImpl                : Rendered criteria query -> select generatedAlias0 from CommentBean as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.topicId=:param0
2017-02-17 13:44:51.347 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : QueryTranslatorFactory : org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory@22d0cb47
2017-02-17 13:44:51.347  INFO 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2017-02-17 13:44:51.422 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.h.i.a.QueryTranslatorImpl            : parse() - HQL: select generatedAlias0 from seconds47.beans.CommentBean as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.topicId=:param0
2017-02-17 13:44:51.444 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.h.i.a.QueryTranslatorImpl            : --- HQL AST ---
 \-[QUERY] Node: 'query'
    +-[SELECT_FROM] Node: 'SELECT_FROM'
    |  +-[FROM] Node: 'from'
    |  |  \-[RANGE] Node: 'RANGE'
    |  |     +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |  |     |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |  |     |  |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'seconds47'
    |  |     |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'beans'
    |  |     |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'CommentBean'
    |  |     \-[ALIAS] Node: 'generatedAlias0'
    |  \-[SELECT] Node: 'select'
    |     \-[IDENT] Node: 'generatedAlias0'
    \-[WHERE] Node: 'where'
       \-[EQ] Node: '='
          +-[DOT] Node: '.'
          |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'generatedAlias0'
          |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'topicId'
          \-[COLON] Node: ':'
             \-[IDENT] Node: 'param0'

2017-02-17 13:44:51.444 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.h.i.a.ErrorCounter                   : throwQueryException() : no errors
2017-02-17 13:44:51.508 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.h.i.a.HqlSqlBaseWalker               : select << begin [level=1, statement=select]
2017-02-17 13:44:51.540 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.h.i.a.t.FromElement                  : FromClause{level=1} : seconds47.beans.CommentBean (generatedAlias0) -> commentbea0_
2017-02-17 13:44:51.542 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.h.i.a.t.FromReferenceNode            : Resolved : generatedAlias0 -> commentbea0_.id
2017-02-17 13:44:51.550 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.h.i.a.t.FromReferenceNode            : Resolved : generatedAlias0 -> commentbea0_.id
2017-02-17 13:44:51.552 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.h.i.a.t.DotNode                      : getDataType() : topicId -> org.hibernate.type.StringType@3af10d0b
2017-02-17 13:44:51.553 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.h.i.a.t.FromReferenceNode            : Resolved : generatedAlias0.topicId -> commentbea0_.topicId
2017-02-17 13:44:51.557 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.h.i.a.HqlSqlBaseWalker               : select : finishing up [level=1, statement=select]
2017-02-17 13:44:51.557 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.h.i.a.HqlSqlWalker                   : processQuery() :  ( SELECT ( {select clause} commentbea0_.id ) ( FromClause{level=1} comments commentbea0_ ) ( where ( = ( commentbea0_.topicId commentbea0_.id topicId ) ? ) ) )
2017-02-17 13:44:51.572 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.h.i.a.u.JoinProcessor                : Using FROM fragment [comments commentbea0_]
2017-02-17 13:44:51.572 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.h.i.a.HqlSqlBaseWalker               : select >> end [level=1, statement=select]
2017-02-17 13:44:51.573 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.h.i.a.QueryTranslatorImpl            : --- SQL AST ---
 \-[SELECT] QueryNode: 'SELECT'  querySpaces (comments)
    +-[SELECT_CLAUSE] SelectClause: '{select clause}'
    |  +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'commentbea0_.id as id1_2_' {alias=generatedAlias0, className=seconds47.beans.CommentBean, tableAlias=commentbea0_}
    |  \-[SQL_TOKEN] SqlFragment: 'commentbea0_.commentDate as commentD2_2_, commentbea0_.commentId as commentI3_2_, commentbea0_.comments as comments4_2_, commentbea0_.topicId as topicId5_2_, commentbea0_.userImage as userImag6_2_, commentbea0_.username as username7_2_'
    +-[FROM] FromClause: 'from' FromClause{level=1, fromElementCounter=1, fromElements=1, fromElementByClassAlias=[generatedAlias0], fromElementByTableAlias=[commentbea0_], fromElementsByPath=[], collectionJoinFromElementsByPath=[], impliedElements=[]}
    |  \-[FROM_FRAGMENT] FromElement: 'comments commentbea0_' FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,not a fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=generatedAlias0,role=null,tableName=comments,tableAlias=commentbea0_,origin=null,columns={,className=seconds47.beans.CommentBean}}
    \-[WHERE] SqlNode: 'where'
       \-[EQ] BinaryLogicOperatorNode: '='
          +-[DOT] DotNode: 'commentbea0_.topicId' {propertyName=topicId,dereferenceType=PRIMITIVE,getPropertyPath=topicId,path=generatedAlias0.topicId,tableAlias=commentbea0_,className=seconds47.beans.CommentBean,classAlias=generatedAlias0}
          |  +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'commentbea0_.id' {alias=generatedAlias0, className=seconds47.beans.CommentBean, tableAlias=commentbea0_}
          |  \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'topicId' {originalText=topicId}
          \-[NAMED_PARAM] ParameterNode: '?' {name=param0, expectedType=org.hibernate.type.StringType@3af10d0b}

2017-02-17 13:44:51.573 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.h.i.a.ErrorCounter                   : throwQueryException() : no errors
2017-02-17 13:44:51.585 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.h.i.a.QueryTranslatorImpl            : HQL: select generatedAlias0 from seconds47.beans.CommentBean as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.topicId=:param0
2017-02-17 13:44:51.586 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.h.i.a.QueryTranslatorImpl            : SQL: select commentbea0_.id as id1_2_, commentbea0_.commentDate as commentD2_2_, commentbea0_.commentId as commentI3_2_, commentbea0_.comments as comments4_2_, commentbea0_.topicId as topicId5_2_, commentbea0_.userImage as userImag6_2_, commentbea0_.username as username7_2_ from comments commentbea0_ where commentbea0_.topicId=?
2017-02-17 13:44:51.586 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.h.i.a.ErrorCounter                   : throwQueryException() : no errors
2017-02-17 13:44:51.645 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.SQL                                  : select commentbea0_.id as id1_2_, commentbea0_.commentDate as commentD2_2_, commentbea0_.commentId as commentI3_2_, commentbea0_.comments as comments4_2_, commentbea0_.topicId as topicId5_2_, commentbea0_.userImage as userImag6_2_, commentbea0_.username as username7_2_ from comments commentbea0_ where commentbea0_.topicId=?
2017-02-17 13:44:51.702 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Written [[]] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@2e3900dc]
2017-02-17 13:44:51.702 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2017-02-17 13:44:51.702 DEBUG 4828 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                : Successfully completed request
```

I don't understand what is the issue here.

Any body please help. I have been trying to fix this from last two days.

Comment: do you get this error from the query or when you return the response?

Comment: @Patrick When I query with request

Comment: I can see you have an entity 'comment' (or something like that) linked to your 'topic' entity. What is the config for your entities? How are you defining the foreign keys? Are you using lazy loading?

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet so I'll write here. The problem might be in your `ResponseEntity`. Please post the code from that class too. Stackoverflow makes me think of recursion and self referencing methods. Anything like that going on anywhere?

Comment: I am not sure what is going on. Struggling for a fix from last 2days with no luck. Expert help needed

Comment: Well an Interface doesn't say much. Please post the ResponseEntity too. Since you get the error when calliing the method the fault is probably somewhere in the method signature or something.

Comment: this is the response entity `return new ResponseEntity(topicBean, HttpStatus.OK);` `ReponseEntity` is inbuilt spring boot class

Comment: oh ok, you see I am not an expert either :) my bad then. but still, the Stackoverflow implicates an uncontrolled call chain. intriguing..

Comment: @kittu Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39970192/spring-security-oauth2-java-config-handler-dispatch-failed-nested-exception-i

Comment: ok I solved it by creating a new repository, service class and service Impl even though its not the correct way.

Comment: I guess the repository was the issue but couldn't figure out underlying issue